# Lately My Photoshop Switched to Saving Images Much Larger in Jpeg format

Tags: adobe-photoshop, jpeg

Images I used to save in various sizes in jpeg format have all switched to being saved as much larger file sizes.

My 12x18 Posters are now 25 Megs instead of 11-17Megs the next size down 6x9 has also increased from 6-10 megs per image to a whooping 15 to 18 megs, the 4x6 print files in CMYK also have increased from 5-7megs per image up to 11megs and up instead and finally the one that actually matters since the rest are fine with me is the web sized versions saved at 80-90% jpeg reduction at 72dpi RGB at 600x900 pixels used to only take up 500kb-900kb and now are running 2megs which is unacceptable for web standards.

I have found a work around in Photoshop using the SAVE for WEB option but that adds an extra step and is limited to 675 pixel wide images for some reason... or that also might be a glitch in the matrix. I'm just wondering what happened, was it a recent update to CS6 that did this? I have never experienced this problem before. My son did mess with the computer so not sure if there is a setting in the preferences dialogue that might have changed all this. I checked through to see but didn't see anything that looked like it would do that. I did add some new action sets to Photoshop I don't think that would affect a flattened Jpeg file though.

Comment: just move the slider. It remembers what you did last time, someone must have maxed the quality.

Comment: _Save for web_ is not an extra step, no—it’s just adding an extra key to your key combo (`Cmd + Alt + Shift + S` on a Mac; presumably `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S` on Windows). _Save for web_ gives you much better control over final output size and quality reduction, plus it gives you a live indicator of the final file size in KB. A 600 × 900 px JPEG image that is 900 KB in size can normally be optimised quite a bit still.

Comment: Save for Web also only does RGB, which might be a problem if OP is looking for CMYK files.

Comment: Are you positive that your source files aren't a higher resolution now for some reason?

Comment: There's also the issue of content. An anime drawing with minimal shading compresses a lot better than a photograph of a hay bale.

Answer (score 2):

When you chose the JPG format and click save, a window appears. The window asks for the quality level. The better the quality, the larger the file will be.

Comment: It has nothing to do with maxing out the slider, I mean I used to save at max 10 in CMYK but those file sizes also increased. Sopmething has changed in photoshop itself. and the save as jpeg dialogue always showed a preview of the final file size as well that is where I first noticed the change because the expected sizes were much larger than I am used to expecting for these size files. I've been saving in 12x18, 6x9 and 4x6 cmyk print size for years as standard poster and flyer sizes. I create all flyers in 12x18 then save and shrink to proportionate sizes. Lately all the sizes are larger.

Answer (score 0):

It is all about **color profiles**

You can flatten your image and press cntrl+A to select all pixels and ctrl+C to copy them to clipboard

Press Ctrl+N or File/New then in preset detail you have an advanced option for color profile. The "Photoshop 5 Default CMYK" and "Photoshop 4  Default CMYK" are legacy options.

Press Ctrl+v and Save As. This brings you back the old file size compression. They change your color code in RGB but no effect on CMYK,so make sure you do this *before* you start design and calibrate your monitor*for your chosen profile in compare to *prints* to get the *same result* from them.